# Spring Boot - Spring Security CSRF protection not injecting token in login page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-two-login-pages) but they have disable the csrf protection.

So I removed the `csrf().disabled()` code but then the code is not being inejected and I cannot login properly because of:

`DEBUG 5276 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter: Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/admin_login`.

I think that there's something missing because of the double configuration (user and admin login).

I have already tried:

- Adding the `<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>` manually
- Adding the `th:action` to the form tag.
- Adding the `<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />` with the `th` tags. This throws: `Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "_csrf.parameterName"`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Put this meta tags in your login page

```
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
 <meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

Then,include the CSRF token in the login form as a hidden parameter manually in the code ( Since you are using Thymeleaf, what you need to do is to use `th:content` instead of `content:`):

```
<input
  type="hidden"
  th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
  th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Comment: Tried and didn't work. It throws an exception. I've updated the post with this case.

Comment: @FernandoFradegrada Did you read the [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token). This way should work.

Comment: @FernandoFradegrada Add thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity namespace and its dependency into your project and try again.In the html tag, add: 
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
In your pom.xml (if you're using Maven) you'll need to add the dependency: thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I used the footage you specified and encountered a similar problem. And I managed to solve this problem.
The reason why the thymeleaf not injecting csrf code below:
Yout login page and processing url according to the article is https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-two-login-pages

```
.loginPage("/loginAdmin")
.loginProcessingUrl("/admin_login")
```

But there are no rules for antMatchers().
I solved this problem by this way:
For App2ConfigurationAdapter add this line of code:

```
.antMatchers("/loginAdmin", "/admin_login").permitAll()
```

Now, thymeleaf inject csrf code into form properly.